# Problem deleting the only node from a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to create a function to delete a certain node if its value matches the value entered by the user. I created a case if there is only a single node, but after deleting the node with `free(curr_node)` and calling `traverse` function, the cmd prints out numbers endlessly. What am I missing?

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

Node *head = NULL;
int node_number = 0;

void traverse(Node *head, int count) {
    int i = 1;

    if(head == NULL) {
        printf("No nodes to traverse!");
        return;
    }

    printf("%d node(s), with their respective value: \n", count);
    while(head != NULL) {
        if(i == count)
            printf("%d\n", head->data);
        else
            printf("%d-", head->data);
        head = head->next;
        i++;
    }
}

void delete_item(Node *head) {
    Node *curr_node = head;

    int value;

    printf("Enter value to search by: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);

    while(curr_node != NULL) {
        if(curr_node->data == value) {
            if(curr_node->next == NULL) {
                free(curr_node);
                head = NULL;
                printf("Node deleted successfully!\n");
                return;
            }
        }
        //curr_node = curr_node->next;
    }
}

Node *create_item() {
    Node *result = NULL;
    result = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if(result == NULL) {
        printf("Couldn't allocate memory!");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Value of node %d: ", node_number + 1);
    scanf("%d", &result->data);
    result->next = NULL;
    node_number++;
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int nodes;

    Node *temp;
    head = create_item();
    
    delete_item(head);
    traverse(head, node_number);

    return 0;
```

Comment: `head` within `delete_item` is a local variable (that contains the address of the list head you passed from the caller). As a result, `head = NULL;` means *nothing* to the caller of this function, except to say it will invalidate the address *still held* by `head` in `main`, and thus any dereference thereafter invokes undefined behavior. Either pass the pointer by address and use indirection to modify it, or return the new list address as a return result, utilizing the otherwise unused function result. It doesn't help that the actual function is broken either.

Comment: @WhozCraig How is it local variable since I made 'head' global above all functions?

Comment: As a general tip, instead of manually handling the information about how many nodes you have like you're currently doing, you can define a proper list type as a `struct` which contains a pointer to the head and a size field that you update every time you add or delete a node.

Comment: `void delete_item(Node *head)` <== not global (and you don't want a global anyway; you can do this with proper argument management of proper types, and/or utilizing your otherwise-unused function result to always return the *current* list head, capturing that result in the caller code).

Comment: @WhozCraig I can use double pointer to pass a reference to head, but that means I have to fix the code since I am passing a double pointer, not a single one or maybe I should pass both `*head` and `**head` and use `**head` only in that case?

Comment: @rdxd thanks, I will try to implement it

Comment: Passing a double pointer to the head is correct because the address which contains the address of the head node remains the same and you can freely modify the proper address of the head.

Comment: @rdxdk i tried it but it didn't work, or I don't do it correctly.

Comment: My bad, I forgot `*` in `head_ref`, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change to `head` is not captured by the caller. The fact is, `head` is actually a *local* variable to `delete_node`, and any changes to it (not to be confused with changed *through* it using deference operations), are not being captured by the caller.

All function arguments in C are *by-value*. Some will say "that's not true for arrays"; they're *wrong*. Used in an expression, the "value" of an array is defined by the language standard as a temporary pointer referring to the address of the first element. I.e. still by-value, its just the value isn't what you may expect. But in your case, `head` is by value. If you had a function `void foo(int x)` you already know that modifying `x` within `foo` does not change the caller's `int` they passed; the same is true here. Just because its a pointer makes no difference. If you want to modify a caller-argument you have to build the road to get there.

There are two general schools around this.

1. Use a pointer to pointer argument and pass the address of `head` in `main`. This requires deference of the pointer-to-pointer to get the actual list head, but also allows you to modify the callers pointer.
2. Use the return result of the function to communicate the current list head back to the caller (i.e. the head after whatever operation is being performed.

The first is more complicated, but allows you to use the return result for other purposes (like error checking, hint). The latter is easier to implement. Both will accomplish what you want. The former is shown below:

```
void delete_item(Node **head) 
{
    int value;

    printf("Enter value to search by: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &value) == 1)
    {
        while (*head)
        {
            if ((*head)->data == value)
            {
                void *tmp = *head;
                *head = (*head)->next;
                free(tmp);
                
                printf("Node deleted successfully!\n");
                break;
            }

            head = &(*head)->next;
        }
    }
}
```

The caller, `main` in this case, needs to be modified as well:

```
delete_item(&head); // <== note passed by address now.
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I did it by passing `*head` and `**head` and using them respectively, but I will consider it a bad practice, I guess? Edit: By the way, why is `&` since (*head) already points to head?

Comment: First, I have no idea what you did at this point. `main` cannot possibly compile properly with the code above if global `head` is declared `Node *head` and you invoke `delete_item(*head);`. that would pass a `Node` where a `Node **` is expected. And that should also answer your question. Passing `&head` from `main` is required because `delete_item` now expects a pointer-to-pointer-to-Node, so that's what we give it: the address of (not in; **of**) a pointer to Node. Remember, pointer variables are still variables. They hold addresses, but they also *have* addresses themselves.

Comment: I mean that I have `void delete_item(Node *head, Node **head_ref)` and pass `delete_item(head, &head)` from `main`. That's what I meant by saying I pass both of them and use them respectively(`**head` for the only node case). I just don't understand why we have `&` in `head = &(*head)->next;` since `*head` is already pointing to the node?

Comment: If you use what I provided, you can do this with *one* argument. To answer your question, what *type* is the `next` member of a node? It's a `Node*` right ? Hence, `&` applied to that will result in a `Node **`, which is exactly what `head` is within the context of the function *I wrote above* . Running this code in a *debugger* and watching what `head` points to, and what `*head` points to, will be a far better hands-on exposure to how this works. I could type for an hour (and in fact have now), but until you see it in action, it won't gel.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I should just re-read it to comprehend it better. Just to ask, is my approach by passing both of them bad practice?

Comment: @zaro there's no reason to do it, and thus every reason not to. The pointer to pointer is all you need, and all that should be exposed as the interface arguments. If you really want to reap the initial pointer you can always do it internal to the function via local variable `Node *myhead = *head_ref;` but as you can see, you don't need to, there is no reason to pass two arguments, and thus every reason *not* to. Anyway, get yourself a debugger, run your program, and put a breakpoint at the call to `delete_item` in main, single-step in, and start watching what happens, step at a time.